# Convert apk into zip flashable in clockWorkMod?

Tags: android, flash, zip, apk

How can i convert an apk into a zip flashable in clockWorkMod? 
I tried using ApkInstaller. It didn't work. Keep getting the error; "installation aborted".

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the .apk extension of your app to .zip  Then put the .zip in your SD card and see if you can flashed with CWM.

I don't know exactly what you want to do, so if you can specify more info that would be great.

If what you want is to simply install an app (.apk) into your phone then you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/install-apk-files-on-android/).

Comment: After rooting my phone, I accidental removed the system launcher so am i cant access any apps on it. When I turn it on it just shows a blank sceen and the notification bar at the top. So I cant install apks in the normal fashion. Thats why i want to try and reinstall the launcher using CMW but to do so it has to be in zip format since CMW doesn't recognize apks. I also tried to reset the phone in CMW, it doesn't work since the launcher is permanently removed from the system.

Comment: 0gravity, I finally managed to find a flashable zip, that restored to original state. So everythings working fine on my phone. But thanks for trying to help.